# Android Bottom Navigation

Tags: android, navigationbar

Здравствуйте.

Есть ли уже полу-официальное решение по внедрению новому `bottomNavigation`?

Видел многие реализации,в том числе https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar, но плохо кастомизируется.

Для меня необходимо,чтобы иконки не закрашивались и менялась сама иконки в завсисимости от стейта active/inactive.

И,как я понял, сейчас все привязывают к `viewPager` и отключают свайп?

[image: картинка]

Спасибо

Comment: Да можно сделать с ViewPager и отключить свайп

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совсем недавно вышло "решение" от гугла [BottomNavigation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html)
В качестве списка айтемов он использует `menu.xml` файл, и для каждого айтема можно насетить свой селектор (`selector.xml`). Но по прежнему там можно менять только цвет, иконку менять нельзя. Думаю, сделано это согласно гайду по материал дизайну. Отключение свайпа по той же причине.

Единственное решение, что бы не менять цвет и менять иконку, есть в [Ahbottomnavigation](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation). Там можно в `listener` настетить изменение айтема, просто удаляя конкретный айтем и добавляя на его место другой (с другой иконкой).